# Setting div background image on demand

Tags: jquery, html, background-image

I'm trying to set background image of a div in android, but when I run my code it does not work...
I'm using android to test it. When I set the background-image via css like this:

```
#defaultHeader {
    height: 65px;
    width:   100%;
    background-image: url('../img/imgSizes/header-640x960.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

It works, but when i try to do it on demand it doesn't...

```
function setHeaderLogo(){
    var size = getWindowScreenSize();
    var path = "../img/imgSizes/" + "header-" + size + ".jpg";
    $('#phoneHeaders #defaultHeader').css("background-image", "url(" + path + ")");  
    $('#phoneHeaders #defaultHeader').css("background-image", "100% 100%");
    $('#phoneHeaders #defaultHeader').css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
}
```

And the div containing this looks like:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="phoneHeaders">
        <div id="defaultHeader">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabletHeaders">
        <div id="defaultHeader">
            Default Tablet Header
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And at the end of the html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setHeaderLogo();
    })
</script>
```

I really have tried it all...I don't know why it does not work..

Comment: Have you tested it with absolute image URL? i.e. `http://` I would recommend you to create CSS class and assign them according to size

Comment: Remove the `background-image", "100% 100%` line and try again. I may elaborate an answer if that works.